# onTap function as parameter is not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created a custom button widget class with Icon and onTap constructors. I want to use this button in any screen with custom icon and custom function on button tapped.

```
class ActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ActionButton({this.icon, this.onPress});
  final FaIcon? icon;
  final Function? onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.2),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
      // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onPress!;
        },
        icon: icon!,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, with this widget I can use this `ActionButton` in any screen with any icon and its action will be any function what I pass as argument.

But when I am using this button on my another page and passing function, function does not get executed:

```
class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product? product;
  const ProductDetailsScreen({Key? key, this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Sizes(context).initSize();
    final double _h = Sizes.screenHeight;
    final double _w = Sizes.screenWidth;
    final _theme = Theme.of(context);

    final product = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Product;
    void _goBack() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      print('the page is popped');
    }

    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: _theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,

      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                ActionButton(
                    icon: FaIcon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                    ),
                    onPress: () {
                      _goBack();
                    }),
                ActionButton(
                  icon: FaIcon(Icons.share),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  child: Image.asset('${product.imageSource}'),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

that_ `goBack()` function is not working
please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: all you need is: `onPressed: onPress,` instead of `onPressed: () { onPress!; },`

Comment: it says The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Comment: so use the same type in your `ActionButton.onPress` as [IconButton.onPressed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/onPressed.html) is using

Answer (score 0):

In Product Details page you need to pass the onPress parameter as follows:

```
ActionButton(icon:FaIcon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                    ),onPress:_goBack)`
```

And in ActionButton class

```
IconButton( onPressed: () { onPress!(); }, icon: icon!, color: Colors.black, ),
```